# using discord.py to get all pinned messages in a channel to

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have created a discord bot that uses pinned messages to display information, so to avoid clutter, I am trying to add a separate function to get rid of all pinned messages.
I have figured out how to unpin a message (unpin()), so am trying to get all the pinned messages so I can run through them and un-pin them.
I've found people saying to use client.pins(channel) and .pins_from(channel) but these both return a no attribute error, so I was wondering what I am doing wrong? thankyou

Answer (score 3):

Use `await TextChannel.pins()` to get all pinned messages

```py
@bot.command()
async def unpinall(ctx):
    pins = await ctx.channel.pins()
    for i in pins:
        await i.unpin()
    await ctx.send("Unpinned all pinned messages!")
```